# Can't use "update" in outputMode() when writing stream data in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I'm trying to write stream data in spark to delta format, but it looks like it won't allow me to use **update** in **outputMode()**, below is my code and error message:

```
deltaStreamingQuery = (eventsDF
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
  .outputMode("update")
  .queryName("stream_1p")
  .start(writePath)
)
```

````
AnalysisException: 'Data source com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.sources.DeltaDataSource does not support Update output mode;'```
````

Answer (score 2):

Currently Databricks Delta only supports `append` and `complete` as `outputMode` for `sinks`.  `append` will add new rows to the table and `complete` will overwrite the table so perhaps this is what you are looking for to incorporate updates.

The official documentation is here => https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-streaming.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I try to use complete, it gives error: **'Complete output mode not supported when there are no streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/Datasets**

Comment: are you doing any aggregations?  you would need to be performing aggregations for complete mode ... try append mode if you aren't performing any aggregations

Comment: this is metadata table streaming job, so I just want to replace old records with new ones, like what update would do

Comment: ok well since you aren't performing aggregation perhaps drop the streaming and just use delta lake to update the table.

Comment: I don't quite understand, I want to keep a streaming job because I want to replace the entire table every time the corresponding input file gets overwritten in my storage for example s3

Comment: delta doesn't appear to support update in streaming mode ... take a look at this though for delta updates https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html ... also kafka sink supports update in streaming mode if you have kafka

Comment: Try updating the table using Merge https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#merge-examples